# Rerouting domains and the need for multiple SSL certificates

Tags: tls, certificates, domain

If a domain URL is registered with a `.com` (`www.example.com`) and we would like to re-route to this domain from a second domain name with a `.com.tr` (`www.example.com.tr`), is this possible?

The `.com` domain is SSL certified.
Do I need a secondary SSL certificate in order to re-route the `.com.tr` domain to the `.com` domain?

Answer (score 5):

You certainly need SSL certificates for both domains.   That does not necessarily mean two separate certificates, however.  While this is not a candidate for a wildcard cert, (since these are two actual domains, and not subdomains of a single domain) but the subject alternate name (SAN) field of a SSL certificate can contain multiple domain names, so you can have both domains listed within a single certificate.   This tends to be more expensive, but also  easier to manage.

Comment: Thank - you for the feedback. What is the purpose of needing to have the certificate on the .com.tr domain ?

Comment: @Nicolette  Really just so that people who attempt to access it over HTTPS can, and are redirected to .com rather than getting an error.  It also provides some measure of protection against an active MitM modifying the response and redirecting users somewhere else instead of your .com site, but that's a pretty small risk.

Comment: @Nicolette, just for your understanding. The Domain in a certificate is used to validate the use for the certificate. so when you use 2 domains you need to have BOTH in your certificate to work. You could also work with 2 separated Certificates and not share the certificates between the (virtual) hosts.  A wildcard certificate only works on the loest part of a domain (so <ANY>.Domain.TLD or *.Domain.TLD) these can not specify additional alternative names so are bound to a single domain tree.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "re-route the .com.tr domain to the .com domain?"

If you only want to redirect users who visit http://www.example.com.tr/ then you don't need a certificate for www.example.com.tr .

If you want to redirect users who visit https://www.example.com.tr without them receiving certificate errors then you will need to present their browser with a certificate for www.example.com.tr .

A single certificate for both names makes things easier. With seperate certificates you would either have to use a seperate IP address for the two names or use server name indication which not all clients support yet.